# Iterative dataframe Output in command line doesn't show but does show in jupyer notebook

Tags: sql, dataframe, lambda, jupyter-notebook

The output from this runs/shows perfectly in Jupyter notebook but when I run the code as a file.py file in IDLE or from the command line the output is an empty dataframe? Any ideas why?
Thanks

```
def selectedManagerOrPeers():
    managerListInput = []
    managerCount = int(input("how many MANAGERS do you want to use?  Enter a quantity: "))
    i=0
    while i < managerCount:
        managerListData = allData[['hID','hName','Min_Date','Max_Date']]
        managerListFind = input('Enter partial or whole MANAGER name: ')
        managerList = managerListData[managerListData['hName'].str.contains(managerListFind, case=False)]
        managerList = managerList.drop_duplicates(subset=['hID', 'hName'])
        managerList = managerList.set_index('hID')
        print(managerList)
        managerID = input('Pick/Type in an MANAGER list ID ("hID") From the List Above: ')
        managerListInput.append(managerID) 
        i += 1

    managerReturns = allData.apply(lambda row: row[allData['hID'].isin(managerListInput)])
    managerReturns = managerReturns.drop(['bhID',
                                           'hID',
                                           'bhName',
                                           'Min_Date',
                                           'Max_Date',
                                           'Strategy',
                                           'SubStrategyName'], axis=1)
    managerReturns = managerReturns.groupby([managerReturns.index, 'hName'])['Returns'].mean().unstack()
    return managerReturns

test = selectedManagerOrPeers()
test
```

Comment: What happens if you run directly with python from a command line?  IE, no IPython, jupyter, or IDLE involved?

Comment: Ran from the command line and got an empty dataframe again.  very frustrating!

Comment: Then this is not an IDLE issue.  You code depends on something special about Jupyter.  I have no idea what, though.  Maybe ask on Jupyter list, if there is one?